# How can I view with web3.js all the ETH transfers to an ethereum address?

Tags: web3js, javascript, address.transfer

How could I list with Web3.js all the ETH transactions to an address?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I am goin to use the EtherScan API:

https://api.etherscan.io/apis